Make MenuBar Popover Work on iOS and Catalyst
I'm trying to implement a menu bar button that presents a popover when it is pressed.
It works as expected on iOS:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
But this is how it works on Catalyst
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
This is the Catalyst-specific code:
struct CatalystHomescreenNavBarButton: View {
    let action: () -> Void
    let iconName: IconName

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action ) {
            iconName.image
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
        .foregroundColor(TOP_BAR_IMAGE_BUTTON_FOREGROUND_COLOR)
        // .hoverEffect() // ignored on Catalyst?
    }
}

CatalystHomescreenNavBarButton(action: { showSearchPopover.toggle() },
                                       iconName: PROJECT_SEARCH_ICON_NAME)
                        .popover(isPresented: $showSearchPopover, attachmentAnchor: 
          .point(.bottom), arrowEdge: .bottom) {
          SearchPopoverContentView()
         .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
}
                        


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iVXSaY1j.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/2J2SmFM6.png

